# split dictionaries based on keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, split

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```
dic = {'shop_2':           date  shop_id  item_id    item_price
                 0   2013-05-12     2    20949         5.0             
                 1   2013-05-13     2    20949         5.0             
                 2   2013-05-17     2    20949         5.0             
                 3   2013-05-19     2    20949         5.0             
                 4   2013-05-21     2    20949         5.0             

 [568 rows x 7 columns],

 'shop_3':           date  shop_id  item_id  item_price
           0   2013-04-24     59    20949         5.0              
           1   2013-04-26     59    20949         5.0             
           2   2013-04-27     59    20949         5.0             
           3   2013-04-28     59    20949         5.0             
           4   2013-04-29     59    20949         5.0             

 [760 rows x 7 columns]}
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a loop yn Python to split the dictionary by its keys into new dataframes. For example, the dataframe shop_2 must have the values of key: shop_2 from the dictionary, the dataframe shop_3 must have the values of key: shop_3 from the dictionary. If I try to access to the keys of the dictionary it already looks like a df but what I need is a loop to create new dataframe for each one of the keys from the dictionary.

Comment: kindly trim the data u shared to a few lines. makes it easy to get a possible solution

Comment: couldnt copy the data. give this a try : ```[value.assign(key = key) for key,value in dic.items()]```

Comment: Can you explain how does it works? the output is a list of the values of the dictionary. This is, instead of accessing to the data inside it by using the keys, now I just have to use the indices and I can manipulate it in an easier way, however the goal is still not reached.

Comment: the value is the dataframe itself, which u can get by just running ```[value for key,value in dic.items()]``` the assign simply hooks the key back to the dataframe. if the goal is not reached, post a visual of what u want to achieve. also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well, cos ur shared data cant be replicated

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a dictionary where the key is a string and the value is a `DataFrame`. It is not clear what you want to do, so I'll offer some options.

If you want to iterate over the dataframes, you would use:

```
for df in dic.values():
    # do something with the dataframe
```

If you just need a list of dataframes, you would use:

```
dfs = list(dic.values())
```

Or if you want to access an individual dataframe

```
shop_2_df = dic.get('shop_2')
```

Comment: What I need to do is the last line you wrote, however, my dictionary has at least 60 keys, that's why I wanted to do a loop which generates each df per key from the dictionary